# How to format values in Google Bar chart API?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I don't figure out well how do I format correctly values vAxis using google bar chart api

I'm using material bars, this is how I'm doing at the moment

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'CHART TITLE',

              },
              bars: 'vertical'


            };

            var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({decimalSymbol: ',',groupingSymbol: '.', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, prefix: 'R$ '});
            formatter.format(data, 1);

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
```

instead that, it does rendering with K char at the end of each value

could you please help me solving this?

regards

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but I think what you're really looking for a localization.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'fr'});
```

The french language localization will default to a comma for a decimal point.

[See the documentation for more details](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements#loadwithlocale).